# How to add menu items in System menu

Tags: menu

I want to insert an item to System menu:

- Help and Support
- About Gnome
- About Ubuntu

More specifically, I want to insert a new item under "About Ubuntu".

Trying with alacarte doesn't work. Cloning "ubuntu-about.desktop" file and changing his attributes doesn't work too (I even rebooted the computer after that). Searching for categories in "/usr/share/desktop-directories" haven't worked too, and searching for "core" and "about" entries in /etc/xdc/menus neither. It isn't as easy as I thought it would be.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I managed to do this a LONG time ago, but I cannot remember how, all remember is something deep down inside some /etc or /usr/share folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add items to the first section of the *System* menu using Alacarte *(System -> Preferences -> Main Menu)*.

The menu items below that are  [hard-coded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding)  in the gnome-panel [source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/maverick/gnome-panel/maverick/annotate/head:/gnome-panel/panel-menu-items.c#L1206), so other than editing the source code, there is no way to add more menu items to the second section of the *System* menu.

However, you can "replace" any of the three menu items by creating a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` with a specific filename.

- *Help and Support* = `yelp.desktop`
- *About GNOME*  =  `gnome-about.desktop`
- *About Ubuntu* = `ubuntu-about.desktop`

For example, lets say that instead of an *About Ubuntu* item in the *System* menu you want an *Ubuntu Tweak* item, simply copy the `ubuntu-tweak.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications/`, renaming it to `ubuntu-about.desktop`:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-tweak.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/ubuntu-about.desktop
```

[image]

If you want to have the *About Ubuntu* menu item again, simply delete `ubuntu-about.desktop`:

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/ubuntu-about.desktop
```

[image]

Comment: Great workaround. I'll change gnome-about.desktop with the shortcut I want. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried navigating to System - Preferences - Main Menu - System - + New Item?  I can add a new menu item this way in Ubuntu 8.04.  However, the problem may be that it doesn't seem to be possible to access the About Ubuntu sub-menu this way.

Comment: Yeah, already tried it, and it doesn't worked.